# android_tutorial_image_transport cannot receive image

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run android_tutorial_image_transport  on android, but cannot receive image from PC, image node on PC is ok,but logcat says :03-15 13:56:37.209: E/UpdatePublisherRunnable(10447): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ubuntu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58257/android_tutorial_image_transport-cannot-receive-image/) by [maoqizhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/4434/maoqizhen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aitana](https://answers.ros.org/users/19803/aitana/) on 2014-07-21**:
I have the same problem as you. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is in translate host name 'ubuntu' ... probaly you haven´t set ROS_IP variable

> export ROS_IP=192.168.0.1 ... for example

and maybe too

> export ROS_HOSTNAME=ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) with karma: 66 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maoqizhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/4434/maoqizhen/) on 2013-03-19**:
I need to set ros_ip in every terminal, and need to run roscore at the same time, any idea to set ros_ip so I don't need to set it in every terminal ?

**Comment by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) on 2013-03-19**:
set ROS_IP in .bashrc file in your home folder  ;-)